# Not Found al redireccionar con htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

Estoy haciendo un "despliegue" de una app en laravel pero estoy teniendo problemas al redireccionar a public/index.php revise este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620505/laravel-htaccess) que al parecer tenia el mismo error.

Pero siempre obtengo error 404 y en los logs de apache me encuentro con lo siguiente:

> [php7:error] [pid 6376:tid 828] [client ::1:54449] script 'C:/laragon/www/app/index.php' not found or unable to stat

virtual host de **sites-enabled**

```
 <VirtualHost *:81> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/sifon/public"
    ServerName sifon.me
    ServerAlias *.sifon.me
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/sifon/public">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride all
     Order allow,deny
     Require all granted
     Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

vhost de httpd-vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\laragon\www\sifon\public"
    ServerName sifon.me
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

basicamente lo que necesito es entrar a localhost/app y que este redireccione a /public/index.php
pero no logro redireccionar a /public/ y que todos los requests sean redirigidos.

digo "despliegue" porque estoy usando laragon para montar el servidor (por cuestiones internas debe ser asi)

Comment: ¿Qué procedimiento seguiste para instalar laravel? ¿Porqué necesitas entrar a la carpeta app del proyecto? ¿Podrías mostrar tu archivo .htaccess con el que tienes problema?

Comment: para instalar laravel se utilizo el de la documentación; no necesito entrar a la carpeta app, app es solo una referencia de mi aplicacion, lo que tengo es lo siguiente: 
www/aplicacion y en laragon lo resuelve como localhost/aplicacion y de ahi necesito redireccionar a localhost/aplicacion/public/index.php para que "funcione". Basicamente no tengo .htaccess en el root solo tengo el que provee laravel por defecto

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que en el archivo de configuración las rutas estén apuntando correctamente a la carpeta `public` del proyecto.
En la ruta `C:\laragon\etc\apache2\sites-enabled\` debe de haber un archivo  `tu_virtualhost.conf`.
En el se encuentra la configuración de tu virtual host y es aquí donde defines la ruta de tu proyecto.
Asegúrate que la variable `DocumentRoot` tenga correcta la ruta a la carpeta `public` de tu proyecto.
También dentro de la etiqueta `<Directory "/ruta_al_proyecto/public">`.
Más o menos así debería de quedar tu archivo.

```text
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/laragon/www/tu_proyecto/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/tu_proyecto/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. 
Y si, si lo tiene solo que DocumentRoot está entre comillas dobles

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el archivo a la pregunta y también describir el proceso de la instalación de tu proyecto? Para poder reproducir tu caso.

Comment: Ya te lo he puesto, la instalación del proyecto fue mover de una pc a otra el proyecto sin usar git